# parseInt returning values that differs by 1

Tags: javascript

I have data like this:

```
var currentValue="12345678901234561";
```

and I'm trying to parse it:

```
var number = parseInt(currentValue, 10) || 0;
```

and my result is:

```
number = 12345678901234560
```

now lets try:

```
currentValue="12345678901234567"
```

in this case `parseInt(currentValue,10`) will result in `12345678901234568`

Can anyone explain me why parseInt is adding/substracting 1 from values provided by me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can anyone explain me why parseInt is adding/substracting 1 from values provided by me?

It's  not, quite, but JavaScript numbers are [IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) (even when you're using `parseInt`), which have only about 15 digits of precision. Your number is *17* digits long, so precision suffers, and the lowest-order digits get spongy.

The maximum reliable integer value is 9,007,199,254,740,991, which is available from the property `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` on modern JavaScript engines. (Similarly, there's `Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER`, which is -9,007,199,254,740,991.)

Some integer-specific operations, like the bitwise operators `~`, `&`, and `|`, convert their floating-point number operands to signed 32-bit integers, which gives us a much smaller range: -2<sup>31</sup> (-2,147,483,648) through 2<sup>31</sup>-1 (2,147,483,647). Others, like `<<`, `>>`, and  `>>>`, convert it to an *unsigned* 32-bit integer, giving us the range 0 through 4,294,967,295. Finally, just to round out our integer discussion, the `length` of an array is always a number within the unsigned 32-bit integer range.